# will_paginate gem cause many warnings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

On my gemfile I am adding the following link:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
```

Then on my console when I run a command I am getting the following warning:

```
warning: previous definition of AttrNames was here
```

Comment: probably related, rails 4.0.1 may fix this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the rails 4.0.1 fixed the problem.